# Toggle classname and remove if clicked on other link with fadein , fadeout effect

Tags: toggle, fadein, fadeout, effect, classname

Here's something that I have

```
link A  Text A    
link B  Text B   
link C  Text C
```

When someone clicks on `Link A`, its color changes to red and the color of text A should also change with fade in / fadeout effect.

Clicking Again on `Link A` will bring link and text to previous style

IF `Link A` is active (i.e color is red), clicking on `Link B` will make `Link A` and `Text A` style to original and `Link B` will become red and the color of `text B` will change with fade in/ out effect .

Does this make sense?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution without fade effect.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#links a').click(function(){
            toggle_link_class(this);
        });

        function toggle_link_class(a){
            $('#links a').removeClass('active'); 
            $('#links a').addClass('inactive'); 
            $(a).toggleClass('inactive active');
        }
    });
</script>

<style>
    #links a{color:#000;}
    #links a.active{color:red;}
</style>

<div id="links">
    <a href="#a">Link A</a> <br />
    <a href="#b">Link B</a> <br />
    <a href="#c">Link C</a> 
</div>
```

You may try below "Color animation Lib"

http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But Tahir, the links are not toggling, like when I click on link A it becomes red, but after clicking link A again nothing happens. I want it to be in original style on second click too ...

Comment: but the code has no issue/bug, its working like a charm. Copy/Paste entire code provide above in a new HTML file and save it, it will work. Check any other issue with your code.

Comment: Oh Tahir, I did that. but the problem where I'm stuck is that It should have toggle effect. Which is not there in your code .. Anyways thank you for your effort Tahir :)